# If $R$ is a right-Noetherian ring and the Jacobson radical satisfies the right Artin-Rees property, then $\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}\text{Jac}(R)^n = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, noetherian

A (two-sided) ideal $I$ of a ring with identity $R$ has the right Artin-Rees property if for any right-ideal $E$ of $R$, there exists an integer $n\geq1$ such that $E\cap I^n\subseteq EI$.

> If $R$ is a right-Noetherian ring and the Jacobson radical $\text{Jac}(R)$ satisfies the right Artin-Rees property, then $\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}\text{Jac}(R)^n = 0$.

I've somehow proved this without the Noetherian property, so my proof most likely is wrong.

Let $J:=\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}\text{Jac}(R)^n$ and suppose $J\not= 0$. Let $x\in J\setminus 0$ and consider the right ideal $xR$. By assumption, we have that $xR \cap \text{Jac}(R)^k \subseteq xR\cdot\text{Jac}(R)$ for some $k$. But $xR\subseteq J\subseteq \text{Jac}(R)^k$ so we get that $xR\subseteq x\text{Jac}(R)$.

Therefore, since $1\in R$, we have that $x=xj$ for some $j\in\text{Jac}(R)$. As the Jacobson radical is right-quasi-regular, $1-j$ has a right inverse $y$. In particular, $x(1-j)=0$ and hence $x(1-j)y=x=0$, contradicting the assumption $x\not=0$.

Is this correct? What is missing?

Comment: Where's the problem come from, out of curiosity?  I don't see any false steps either after reading it a couple times.

Comment: My ring theory class. It is not from a book, but from a set of lecture notes. From what I've looked around it seems the result is true. (albeit the paper stated it as a 'well-known' result).

Comment: Lucky you :)   Then it will make for a good question.  I'd be curious to know what the resolution is.

Comment: Does the proof look correct to you?

Comment: It seems very straightforward: I can't spot any gap. If I were you I'd just present this to the prof in office hours or something to check if there is something i'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your teacher was thinking to Nakayama’s lemma. By assumption, there exists $n$ such that
$$
J\cap (\operatorname{Jac}(R))^n\subseteq J\operatorname{Jac}(R)
$$
On the other hand, $J=J\cap (\operatorname{Jac}(R))^n$ and $J\operatorname{Jac}(R)\subseteq J$, so we conclude
$$
J\operatorname{Jac}(R)=J
$$
Since $J$ is finitely generated, because $R$ is right Noetherian, we have $J=0$ by Nakayama’s lemma.

You showed instead that every cyclic submodule of $J$ is zero (using an abridged version of Nakayama’s lemma) and the proof is correct. So the hypothesis that $R$ is right Noetherian can be removed.